# Detached database with renamed drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, attach

I have detached a database and had the systems team rename the drive letter (from `E:` to `P:`). When I try to attach the database again, it's looking for the original drive.

I don't have a backup of the database. Is there any way I can change the system tables where the actual physical locations of the files (`.mdf`) are stored?

Are there any alternative solutions now?

Just to be clear: It's my mistake that I approved the systems team to change the drive letter.

Comment: Please edit the question and describe what steps, exactly, you are taking when attaching the db is attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the path for every database file (including ldf file) and SQL Server will not look for the original path. If the GUI does something strange, then use the `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH` directly (examples in the [product documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database), for instance).